# UTL_FILE.FOPEN file name not UTF-8 (umlauts)

Tags: oracle, plsql, utf-8

I want to create a new file in the output path of my oracle 19.18 database with this line of code:

```
UTL_FILE.FOPEN(<path>, 'ÄÖÜ.txt', 'w');
```

But the generated file on disk is:

```
Ã„Ã–Ãœ.txt
```

The character set is:

```
NLS_CHARACTERSET    AL32UTF8
```

What did I wrong? Btw the content of the file is correct UTF-8.

Before we updated the database to UTF-8 we had ANSI and there was no problem with file names:

```
NLS_CHARACTERSET    WE8ISO8859P15
```

It seems the file name is always interpreted as ANSI.

Comment: How do you execute this command? What do you get from `select DUMP('ÄÖÜ', 1016) from dual;`?

Comment: I execute it in Oracle SQL Developer v18.4.0.376

Comment: The output is: Typ=96 Len=6 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: c3,84,c3,96,c3,9c

Comment: "But the generated file on disk is: Ã„Ã–Ãœ.txt" how are you viewing the generated file name? Have you tried other languages (such as Python, Java, C, etc.) or different software (such as Notepad, etc.) and using that to try to create a file with the same UTF8 name and seen whether that also has the same issues when you use the same method to view the file name? (I.e. please check that this is an Oracle problem and not a whatever you are using to view the file details' problem.)

Comment: @MT0 I'm viewing it in Windows Explorer (Win 2016 Server). I also tried it in SQLPlus command line... no change. Also tried to generate a new file with notepad, this is working correctly.

Comment: What did you try in SQLPlus? UTF-8 support in sqlplus is bad. And UTF-8 support in Windows `cmd` is also bad. I am not familiar with SQL Developer, maybe have a look at https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/sqldeveloper-editor-encoding-7422#comment_323523248168783390434941382882176426817

Comment: You face a [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case (*example in Python for its universal intelligibility*): `'ÄÖÜ.txt'.encode( 'utf-8').decode( 'cp1252')` returns `'Ã„Ã–Ãœ.txt'`…

Comment: Are you able to create the file with such a name dorectly (i.e. not via Oracle)? Been a while but I think still when dealing with character set conversions, the `NLS_LANG` environment variable is via. This directs  the program (sqlplus) towards the intended behaviour.  See here https://docs.oracle.com/en/industries/health-sciences/life-sciences-data-hub/3.0/install-guide/set-nls_lang-environment-variable-utf8.html#GUID-D6F65696-D385-4DCE-8623-CCF96AE06A0A